# Php extract date for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

I am trying to convert a date that I parse from a file "September 2, 1904" . How can I convert that to MySQL date format for be able to insert it in MySQL? If insert it like this i get "0000-00-00" in MySQL

I tried something like :

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $data[11]);
            //echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use `strtotime`.

Comment: If you use `createFromFormat`, you have to make the format match the date that you read from the file. `j-M-Y` is for `2-09-1904`, not `September 2, 1904`.

Answer (score 2):

I usually rely on strtotime to parse dates if the format can be trusted...

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime("September 2, 1904"));
```

Comment: please also mark as answered as other users of SO can learn from it or can see that it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this?

mktime(0,0,0,9,2,1904)